# Changing options in HTML <selecet>based on result of another select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I put my code in a jsfiddle so it might be easier to read and debug. No matter what option I select from the list, it thinks it's the 'Single room' value that I've chosen. It is supposed to display odd numbers up to 5 if the room is a single room and , even number if double room selected (and < 7) and for the family room the numbers shown should only be 7.

Here's the fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/35rchfup/

Thanks to anyone who can help in advance.

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="chooseRoomType">Choose room 
type:</label>
<div class="col-md-4">
<label class="select" for="chooseRoomType">
  <div class="select">
    <select class="form-control" runat="server" id="chooseRoomType" onchange="showValidRooms">
      <option value="0">Choose room</option>
      <option value="1">Single room</option>
      <option value="2">Double room</option>
      <option value="3">Family room</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</label>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="chooseRoomNo">Choose room number:
</label>
 <div class="col-md-4">
   <label class="select" for="chooseRoomNo">
     <div class="select">
      <select class="form-control" runat="server" id="chooseRoomNo">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</label>
 </div>
```

```
<script>
   document.getElementById("chooseRoomType").onchange = function() {
 showRooms()
};

function showRooms() { //chooses single room every time
  var select = document.getElementById("chooseRoomNo");
  var selectedValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  if (selectedValue == 1) {
$('#chooseRoomNo')
  .empty()
  .append('<option value="1">1</option>', '<option value="3">3</option>', 
'<option value="5">5</option>');
 } else if (selectedValue == 2) {
   $('#chooseRoomNo')
     .empty()
     .append('<option value="2">2</option>', '<option value="4">4</option>', 
  '<option value="6">6</option>');
   } else if (selectedValue == 3) {
    //show family room (number 7)
    $('#chooseRoomNo')
     .empty()
     .append('<option value="7">7</option>');
 } else if (selectedValue == 0) {
    alert("You must choose a room type.");
}

 console.log(selectedValue);//always 1
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed your example: https://jsfiddle.net/35rchfup/2/

You had two issues:

1) You were referring to the wrong dropdown (`var select = document.getElementById("chooseRoomNo");`)

2) You were not calling the function onchange (`<select class="form-control" runat="server" id="chooseRoomType" onchange="showValidRooms">`) that is anyway useless because you bind your event through JavaScript

Here your example:

```js
document.getElementById("chooseRoomType").onchange = function() {
  showRooms()
};

function showRooms() { //chooses single room every time
  var selectedValue = $("#chooseRoomType").val();
  if (selectedValue == 1) {
    $('#chooseRoomNo')
      .empty()
      .append('<option value="1">1</option>', '<option value="3">3</option>', '<option value="5">5</option>');
  } else if (selectedValue == 2) {
    $('#chooseRoomNo')
      .empty()
      .append('<option value="2">2</option>', '<option value="4">4</option>', '<option value="6">6</option>');
  } else if (selectedValue == 3) {
    //show family room (number 7)
    $('#chooseRoomNo')
      .empty()
      .append('<option value="7">7</option>');
  } else if (selectedValue == 0) {
    alert("You must choose a room type.");
  }

  console.log(selectedValue);//always 1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="chooseRoomType">Choose room type:</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label class="select" for="chooseRoomType">
      <div class="select">
        <select class="form-control" runat="server" id="chooseRoomType">
          <option value="0">Choose room</option>
          <option value="1">Single room</option>
          <option value="2">Double room</option>
          <option value="3">Family room</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="chooseRoomNo">Choose room number:</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label class="select" for="chooseRoomNo">
      <div class="select">
        <select class="form-control" runat="server" id="chooseRoomNo">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The onchange property for the list shouldn't still be there, I forgot to remove it from an earlier test. I removed this when I seen it but I forgot to change the fiddle code. Thanks.

Comment: yep update the answer, you can directly remove it :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `var select = document.getElementById("chooseRoomType");` in your function `showRooms()` instead of `var select = document.getElementById("chooseRoomNo");`. Because you are getting value of the second dropdown which is always 1 by default.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are choosing the wrong DropDown:

```
function showRooms() { //chooses single room every time
  var select = document.getElementById("chooseRoomNo");// This should be "chooseRoomType"
  var selectedValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  if (selectedValue == 1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you were calling roomnumber selector instead of roomtype.

Comment: Here is the JS Fiddle link
[https://jsfiddle.net/ghayyourspyko/35rchfup/5/]

Answer (score 0):

Beside all the other answers pointing to your typo, here's how I'd do it:
using some clearly defined room-logic, and `show/hide`

All you need:

```
var roomLogic = {
  0 : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
  1 : [1,3,5],
  2 : [2,4,6],
  3 : [7]
};

$("#chooseRoomType").on("change", function() {

  var type = this.value;  

  $("#chooseRoomNo").find("option").hide().filter(function() {
    return  $.inArray( +this.value, roomLogic[type] ) > -1; 
  }).show().eq(0).prop("selected", true);

});
```

Here's a full demo:

```js
var roomLogic = {
 0 : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
  1 : [1,3,5],
  2 : [2,4,6],
  3 : [7]
}

$("#chooseRoomType").on("change", function() {

  var type = this.value;  
  
  $("#chooseRoomNo").find("option").hide().filter(function() {
   return  $.inArray( +this.value, roomLogic[type] ) > -1; 
  }).show().eq(0).prop("selected", true);
  
  // if (type==0) alert("You need to select a room");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="chooseRoomType">Choose room type:</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label class="select" for="chooseRoomType">
      <div class="select">
      <!--  onchange="showValidRooms" ??? -->
        <select class="form-control" runat="server" id="chooseRoomType">
          <option value="0">Choose room</option>
          <option value="1">Single room</option>
          <option value="2">Double room</option>
          <option value="3">Family room</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="chooseRoomNo">Choose room number:</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label class="select" for="chooseRoomNo">
      <div class="select">
        <select class="form-control" runat="server" id="chooseRoomNo">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

One day, if your room logic changes, all you need to carelessly edit is the `var roomLogic`. Nothing else.

Comment: I like this way of doing it, truth is I never considered it. I've just recently learned javascript to improve the quality of my college project so I'm not very good at it but I appreciate the alternative method. Thanks!